# LXPANEL directory menu not working

Tags: lxde, lxpanel

My OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LXPanel Version : 0.5.8 Installation worked very well. But the "Directory Menu" on the taskbar doesn't work. When I click on it, it show me a list including "Desktop, Download, Documents .... ", each has a submenu with "Open, Open in terminal" When I clicked on "Open" or "Open in terminal", nothing happened. What could be the reason?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can change these entries in the configuration file for the panel to what is originally used for the default panel session:

1. Open `~/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/config` in a text editor.
2. Change the entries for FileManager and Terminal:

   ```
   [Command]
   FileManager= pcmanfm %s
   Terminal=lxterminal
   Logout=lxsession-default quit
   ```
3. Save file and restart panel:

   ```
   lxpanelctl restart
   ```

Directory Menu plugin will work again. Of course, you could also change the entries to commands for a different file manager or terminal application.